# código de conversão do google ads

Tags: html, google, instalador, html-tags

Boa tarde a todos!! 
Tudo bem?
eu criei uma tag de conversão do google ads, que deve ser disparada ao clicar no link do whatsapp do meu site, mas não estou conseguindo instalar corretamente no gatilho, que é o botão do whats(é um href)...eu lancei um "onclick" mas a menina do goolge disse que desse jeito, esta errado...
Eu vou postar o código, vocês me ajudam??
esse é a tag global:

```
    <!-- 
    Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: ********** -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW- 
    **********"></script>
    <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'AW-******************'); 
    </script>
```

Snipet é esse cara que informa o click segundo a galera da google :

```
     <script>
      function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
      var callback = function () {
      if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
      }
      };
      gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-***************/*******************',
      'event_callback': callback
      });
       return false;
      }
      </script>
```

o problema é que o gatilho aqui é o click em um botão, que é uma imagem ou texto...eu não estou sabendo como colocar esse código noS botõeS...alguém aí sabe? poderia me ajudar, por favor??
Obrigado a todos!!!
Grande abraço!!!

Answer (score 0):

já solucionei esse problema utilizando JS com Jquery, assim:

```
    $('a[href*="whatsapp"]').click(function(){
      gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-***************/*******************',
      'event_callback': callback
      });

});
```

De forma resumida, ao detectar no DOM um click onde o href tenha a palavra whatsapp (link da API padrão do Whatsapp, por exemplo) ele fará o call da gtag.

Ah, o href vai fazer o request do endereço do Whatsapp, mas dá tempo do script rodar antes do carregamento.

Legal? Espero ter ajudado